# Get an image from URL and upload it to Firebase Storage

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, file-upload, firebase-storage

Is it possible to write a function to get an image from a url such as https://website.com/images/myImage.jpg and then automatically upload it to a Firebase Storage bucket?

I am trying to do it with multiple images in one go but am struggling to get one to work at the moment. My best attempt so far has seen me having to download the images, save them in the Media Library and then send them all up to Firebase, which surely cannot be the most efficient way?

In a nutshell, I have 10 images with URL's like the above and, when the function is fired I need them all to upload to my storage bucket, without the need to save them to the users device library.

Does anyone have any ideas on the most efficient way to do this please?

Comment: I think you are using the key word, you want to “upload” not link, to upload you need to download. You can do it on the users device or via a cloud function.

Comment: I've actually figured another way around it all now so will not be using this solution (if one comes up). I would still be intrigued to know if there is a way to automate this without the need to download the images first :)

Comment: You don't have to store the images in the media library, you can instead save them as files using `FileManager`. If you don't want the user's device to download the images at all, you can write a Firebase cloud function that you'll call passing a URL of the image, and the function will download it and store in the Storage.